# How much space do VIEWS occupy in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, view, size, storage

If I store my query results as *views* does it take more space of my memory in comparison to a table with query results?

Another question about views is that can I have new query based on the results of a query that is stored as views?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Question 1**

To answer your first question, you cannot store your query results as views but you can achieve a similar functionality using PostgreSQL's `trigger` feature.

PostgreSQL supports creation of `views` natively but not the creation of `materialized views` (views that store your results) - but this can be handled using triggers. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views

views do not take up RAM ("memory").

**For Question 2**

And to answer the second question, to update a view in postgresql, you will need to use `CREATE RULE` - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/sql-createrule.html

> CREATE RULE defines a new rule applying to a specified table or view. CREATE OR REPLACE RULE will either create a new rule, or replace
>   an existing rule of the same name for the same table.

Comment: Thank you. If I use `trigger` and have query results in my DB, then what will be actual storage in my hard disk? Will it be less than a table with the same data?

Comment: @f.ashouri: `trigger` does not take up additional "disk storage" to any significant extent because it is actually not a `materialized view`.  All `trigger` does is to set off a specific query at run time at the occurrence of a particular event, such as a query asking for results from a pre-created view. See http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-trigger-for-beginners/  `PostgreSQL` does not support true `materialized views` at this point in time of writing so using `trigger` on a `view` is essentially a work-around.

Comment: I should point out that Materialized Views are available in PostgreSQL 9.3.

Answer (score 9):

Views don't store query results, they store queries.

Some RDBMS allow the way to store query results (for some queries): this is called *materialized views* in `Oracle` and *indexed views* in `SQL Server`.

`PostgreSQL` does not support those (though, as @CalvinCheng mentioned, you can emulate those using triggers or rules).

Yes, you can use views in your queries. However, a view is just a convenient way to refer to a complex query by name, not a way to store its results.

Comment: @f.ashouri: materialized views store query definition and results, simple views only store the query definition. `PostgreSQL` does not support materialized views.

Comment: @f.ashouri When you say "memory", it isn't at all clear if you mean RAM or disk storage. If you meant RAM: Views have no effect on RAM; it's as if you wrote the underlying `SELECT` that defines the view in a subquery.

Comment: @Quassnoi - it's true that `PostgreSQL` does not support materialized views. However, one can achieve what materialized views do by using triggers. See http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views

Answer (score 2):

I would like to point out that as of Postgres 9.3, Materialized Views [are supported](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/rules-materializedviews.html)

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL view is a saved query. Once created, selecting from a view is exactly the same as selecting from the original query, it returns the query each time. so views do not take up memory.

You can not store your query results as views, views are just queries, but you can achieve a similar functionality using materialized views. Materialized views they are only updated on demand. Second, the whole materialized view must be updated; there is no way to only update a single stale row.

So in that case you have to eagerly update view whenever a change occurs that would invalidate a row. It can be done with triggers.